# if something list something with limit else list all in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out at this point how to display only a certain amount of categories based on a user plan. So in my controller I have the following;

```
def check_plan?
  User.current.plan_id == "" && User.current.bins.count == 2 || User.current.plan_id ==     "nil" && User.current.bins.count == 2
end
helper_method :check_plan?
```

NOTE: I know, not pretty but it will do for now. So basically :check_plan? checks a few things.

Now I thought, that I could use that for our category list as a starting point, so that if the user isn't on any plan, they are limited in showing 2 if they are on a plan it shows them all. Here's what I thought would work but it doesn't. I've done it before but can't remember exactly how it went, so any help is appreciated.

```
<% if check_plan? %>
   <% @bin_list.order("position").limit(2).each do |bin| %>
<% else %>
   <% @bins_list.order("position").each do |bin| %>
<% end %>
```

Not really working and I know why, but their will all my other tries with bringing any of those lines together with check_plan.

Comment: Have you tested each of the values in your check_plan? method to be sure they are returning what you expect?

Comment: :check_plan works fine.. I've also tried doing `if check_plan? @bin_list.order("position").limit(2).each do |bin|` then the content then `end else @bin_list.order("position").each do |bin|` however its telling me `unexpected keyword_else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such logic belongs to Model natually. Don't abuse helper.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def bin_limit
    check_plan? ? 0 : 2
  end

  def check_plan?
    # Your logic
  end

  def bins_with_limit
    bins.with_limit(bin_limit)
  end

end 

class Bin < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_limit(limit)
    return self if limit <=0
    self.limit(limit)
  end
end
```

View

```
current_user.bins_with_limit.each do |bin|
```

Comment: @user2419316, my pleasure :) My last line of code has some problem. The method should be called on user instance, not User class. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the rails method `.blank?` will return true for either "" or nil, so you can start by refactoring your code as follows:

```
def check_plan?
  ( User.current.plan_id.nil? || User.current.plan_id.blank? ) && User.current.bins.count == 2 
end
helper_method :check_plan?
```

Secondly, you're calling blocks in the code below, so you'll need to complete them with `end`

```
<% if check_plan? %>
   <% @bin_list.order("position").limit(2).each do |bin| %>
   <% end %>
<% else %>
   <% @bins_list.order("position").each do |bin| %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

*Of course, you'll want to put whatever you're doing with `bin` between the `do` and `end` portions above.*

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and you're right. In terms of .blank? yes, it does work same way, I actually forgot all about .blank? and was dealing with it not working on .empty? which is why I've added few other options to that line. Thanks again!

Comment: `String#blank?` doesn't catch `"nil"` which is matched in OP's original code. However, this looks rather weird in the first place...

Comment: Secondly, yes `User.current.plan_id.blank?` and `User.current.bins.count` do return the values we expected. I just think my original question line has too much of something.

Comment: Holger as weird as it might be, its a quick fix for now until I can push something better out, just tight for timeline with my boss :)

Comment: I thought `String#blank?` does catch `nil`, but if not, you can easily add the test for `User.current.plan_id.nil?` in there as well.  That said, I would also look at @billy-chan's answer about putting the logic in your model.